# UIActivityindicator won't be displayed upon Modalviewcontroller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiactivityindicatorview, modalviewcontroller

i've created a login screen via a modalviewcontroller. But certainly i have a problem to display a uiactivityindicator once the loginbutton was pressed. 
Instead the activityindicator seem to be displayed for a minimal period of time, when releasing the modalviewcontroller.
Does anyone know the problem.
Could anybody help me out?
Thanks a lot.
Greetz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got the solution.

Apple seems to combine animations. So the animation of dismissng the modalview and startanimating function of the uiactivityindicator are combined to one action 
and the animation of the activityindicator will be never shown.

*Simple hack*:
Just wait with the dismissal of the modalview for a short time e.g.

```
[self performSelector:@selector(hideLogin) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
```